# How to create an Access query to find # symbol into a field?

Tags: mysql, select, ms-access, odbc

It seems easy but I'm missing something. I have a MySQL database that is connected from access through ODBC connector.

I'm looking for the fields where there are # symbol but I'm getting zero results, although I have a field with # (Access query).

**Data**

```
id    obs
1     #rejected
```

**Access Query** where I do not have any results

```
SELECT id, obs
FROM Person
WHERE obs Like '*#*'
```

+info added from answers

**MySQL Query** works fine

```
SELECT id, obs
FROM Person
WHERE obs Like '%#%'

SELECT id, obs
FROM Person
WHERE obs LOCATE('#',obs) >0
```

Which is the escape character in Access?
Any ideas to fix Access query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Access you can use:

```
WHERE obs LIKE '*[#]*'
```

There are three wildcard characters in Access that can be used with `LIKE` operator:

```
`*` for a string of arbitrary length (equivalent ANSI: `%`)
`?` for a single character (equivalent ANSI: `_`)
`#` for a single numeric digit 
`[` for escaping
```

If you want to search for one of those wildcards, you have to enclose them in brackets: `[ ]`

You can find more info in the msdn article: [Separate But Equal Wildcard Characters in SQL Server and Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260420%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

To only check the occurrence of '#'  you can use [**LOCATE()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_locate)

```
SELECT id, obs
FROM Person
 WHERE LOCATE('#',obs) >0
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f1f0e/5)

For you access query

```
SELECT id, obs
FROM Person
 WHERE obs Like '*[#]*'
```

Comment: You can remove the fiddle demos. SQL-Fiddle does not support Access.

Comment: @ypercube thanks i have updated my answer and removed fiddle for second query i have posted solution for mysql but my answer was edited by someone for access query

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the '*' with '%' as

```
SELECT id, obs
FROM Person
WHERE obs Like '%#%'
```